# Getting SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: ssl

This seems to be a popular question.  I hope to differentiate my version from the others.  Here's what I'm seeing when trying to connect to a Tomcat server, using the -debug option:

```
# openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x694230 [0x694ef0] (187 bytes => 187 (0xBB))
[...]
read from 0x694230 [0x69a450] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                              ......(
15633:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:610:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the response does not include visible characters, so I'm unlikely to be connecting to a non-SSL-enabled port.  I'm not certain which SSL library my version of openssl is using, but looking at https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/2214/ssl/s23_clnt.c is helpful, even with the wrong line numbers.  p[1] is 0x03, which is SSL3_VERSION_MAJOR, and p[2] is 0x03, which is TLS1_2_VERSION_MINOR. p[0] is 0x15 (21 decimal), which is SSL3_RT_ALERT, which means that p[3] and p[4] should be 0 and 2 (the code doesn't use symbolic names for these), which they are.  p[5] is also 0x02, which is SSL3_AL_FATAL, which doesn't look good. I'm guessing the server didn't like my initial write.  However, that should give me a different error, so I'm wondering if openssl really doesn't recognize an otherwise valid protocol.  Checking the version:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
```

Yes, that looks a bit old.  I guess I need to find a more recent version.

Comment: The GnuWin version (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) is OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008.  Bah!

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.8 did not implement TLS1.2 (wire version 03 03) or 1.1 (03 02) either. Only OpenSSL 1.0.1 and up implement TLS1.1 and 1.2 (and only 1.0.2 up is currently supported). If you want a current Windows build of OpenSSL, goto http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (note: includes both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows, in spite of the URL).